# Query field has to match multiple values

Tags: mysql

I'm currently having an issue with my query and i can't figure out the final step in order to make it work.
The problem is that i have a filter option on my website which gives visitors the possibility to filter on specific settings.

My query so far is

```
SELECT DISTINCT `spt`.`title`
FROM `shop_product_specs` as `sps` JOIN
     `shop_product_texts` as `spt`
     ON `spt`.`product_id` = `sps`.`product_id`
WHERE `cat_spec_id` IN (2, 3) AND (`value` IN ("1200", "1400")) AND (`value` IN ("A", "A+"))
```

What i am trying to accomplish is that when i execute the query the value field matches multiple values.

So for example i want a product which has the cat_spec_id of 2 with the value of 1200 or 1400 BUT ALSO matches cat_spec_id of 3 with the value of "A" or "A+".

The main problem of the query is that it is the same field, so is this even possible?

This is my structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shop_product_specs` (
  `product_spec_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_spec_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_spec_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `cat_spec_id` (`cat_spec_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=312 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an example of a set-within-sets subquery.  Here is a method that solves this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
SELECT  `spt`.`title`
FROM `shop_product_specs` as `sps` JOIN
     `shop_product_texts` as `spt`
     ON `spt`.`product_id` = `sps`.`product_id`
group by spt.title
having max(cat_spec_id = 2 and value in ('1200', '1400')) > 0 and
       max(cat_spec_id = 3 and value in ('A', 'A+')) > 0
```

Each of the conditions in the `having` clause is verifying that a row exists with the corresponding conditions.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i was looking for and there was no way i could figure this out myself! You're the man!